# Python Pandas: Filtering Against String Works, Against Datetime Fails

Tags: python, pandas

How can I filter a Pandas dataframe with a datetime64 value?

With a string elementary value, filtering is possible:

```
df = df[df['date_in_string_format'] < '2017-07-01']
```

=> success

With a Series in datetime64 format, I get an error:

```
df['date_in_datetime64_format'] = map(pd.to_datetime, \
    df['date_in_string_format'], '%Y-%m-%d')

df = df[df['date_in_datetime64_format'] < pd.datetime(2017,7,1)]
```

=> results in:

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'map' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not see why we need  `map` here

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2017-01-01','2017-07-19']})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df[df['Date'] < pd.datetime(2017,7,1)]

Out[1674]: 
        Date
0 2017-01-01
```